# Store Listview into SQLite table

Tags: android

I have a listview that returns carmodels, with a radiogroup which allows a user to select the condition of the car.  I'm trying to save this info into a sqlite table.

```
  void addListItem(List<Car> listItem) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  for (int i = 0; i < listItem.size(); i++) {

  Log.e("value inserting==", "" + listItem.get(i));
  values.put(DBHelper.CARID, listItem.get(i));
  values.put(DBHelper.CARMAKE, listItem.get(i));
  values.put(DBHelper.CONDITION, listItem.get(i));
  db.insert(TABLE_CARCONDITION, null, values);

  }

  db.close(); // Closing database connection
```

}

In my main activity I also have added the new code below. I'm passing my Listview, Condition (which is the radio button selection) and a timestamp. I fixed my null reference pointer issue.  Now I need to make sure I'm looping through all listview items to pull the selected radiobutton.  Because as it is now only brings back the first hit.

```
  View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {

  DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

  String Condition=null;

  switch (rvalue.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
     case R.id.a1:
        Condition="r1";
        break;
     case R.id.a2:
        Condition="r2";
        break;
     case R.id.a3:
        Condition="r3";
        break;
     case R.id.a4:
        Condition="r4";
        break;
  }

  db.addListItem(listCars,Condition,getCurrentTimeStamp());
  }
  };
  save.setOnClickListener(onSave);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `List<Car>`. `listItem.get(i)` returns a `Car` object. You need information about the `Car` object, not the `Car` object itself (and you cannot store a `Car` object in `ContentValues`).

```
void addList(List<Car> cars) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    for (Car car : cars) {
        Log.e("value inserting==", "" + car.toString());
        values.put(DBHelper.CARID, car.getId());
        values.put(DBHelper.CARMAKE, car.getMake());
        values.put(DBHelper.CONDITION, car.getModel());
        db.insert(TABLE_CARCONDITION, null, values);
    }
    db.close();
}
```

If your `Car` doesn't have methods to access its data, add them.

Comment: Thanks for that Karakuri. One other question...I've added an "onSave" listener but getting "null" object reference.  Not sure what I'm missing/doing wrong.  I updated my code above with the radio button selections.

Comment: @neo ask a new question and include a complete stack trace from logcat.

Comment: I fixed the error, but now I'm working on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773580/linking-radiobutton-value-to-correct-listview-item?noredirect=1#comment51479969_31773580

Answer (score 0):

When store an element in ListView by listItem.get(i) is storing a memory address. I think this cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used List listItem, every time you call listItem.get(i), you are getting one Car object, and Put does't know anything about Car Class.

Just create a toString method withing your Car Class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.<someproperty of Car>;
}
```

last but not least, add .toString() when you call listItem.get(i)

```
values.put(DBHelper.CARID, listItem.get(i).toString());
```